# Ask a contact to fill his own contact information in Outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

What would be the best way about this?

Basically my idea is that I have a bunch of emails (say, 500) and would like to send them some sort of pre-determined form to fill out their information, such as First Name, Surname, Phone number or Company they work for.

Then I would love if their reply auto-turned to the contact information. This should be possible with VBA, but I wanted to ask what's the common way to achieve this as I expect it to be quite a frequent problem (ie. you want to ask your customer if their info is up to date, so you send him his info and he corrects what's not up-to-date).

Comment: Is Outlook Web App available to your company (also called 'OWA')? If so, there are some built in fields they can edit there which may cover your desired updates.If you have OWA i'll provide an answer for using it.

Comment: I do not believe it has - this is a very small company that employed me recently and when I saw the state their contacts are I simply /facepalmed. I do not have experience with OWA, how do I find if the company I work for has it or doesn't have it?

Comment: Hmm @emihir0 I may have misunderstood you. Are the contacts you want to update for internal users or for external clients? If they are internal users and you are on Exchange there are relatively easy ways to to get internal users to update their own data. If these are external contacts it may be harder. Could you provide which email system you are using and if the contacts are internal to your organization or contacts in an outside organization

Comment: @Abraxas I'm sorry about not being clear about that. It is contact information for in our local outlook client only. Basically - a very small company where only 1 computer is used to communicate with our clients and so it is more convenient to keep everything there. So we have an Outlook setup to our own email domain through it to receive and send emails - these emails are sent manually now and there are no mailing list (simply 500 +/- out of date contact info but with correct email address). So I wanted to update these contact infos before creating mailing lists.